# Where can I find out more about Aura-ExtJS (Lightning Components combined with Sencha's Ext.js library)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I heard about this at DF14 and wanted to know more!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've just opened up access to the [aura-extjs](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura-extjs) github repo and published a corresponding managed package on AppExchange. Please see the README for more details.